# Mixing secure and non-secure pages

Tags: apache, drupal, https

I am using the Drupal Secure Pages module to secure sensitive pages (such as login and admin pages). I am running into two issues with this:

1. I am able to login securely on the login page using https. However when I traverse to a non-secure page such as the home page, the browser completely forgets that I am logged in (instead of my username, the login link shows up). (The problem goes away as soon as I disable the Secure Pages module.)
2. Since the secure pages are getting their images using non-secure URLs, the browsers are showing warning messages. For example, "The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page."

- Is there any clean solution to these issues?
- The recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361829/mixing-secure-and-non-secure-content-on-web-pages-is-it-a-good-idea) was to make the entire site secure, which seems like an overkill for my site (essentially an open source community). Having said that, how much of a performance hit does something like this incur, roughly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with non-secure pages not remembering the login state. The solution was to add this line to sites/default/settings.php: $conf['https'] = TRUE; You can see the details [here](http://drupal.org/https-information).

As far as I can tell, issue #2 was a browser caching issue. I cleared all the caches and cookies and the problem seems to have gone away!